# How can I ignore the last element of an array if i sum the actual element less next element?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to obtain the subtraction of each element less the next element, for example:
179522-179552,179552-179747...and so on; the problem is when the last part doesn't have the following value; it throws an error -> PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 16, which is the final position of my array.

```
$number =array(179522,
               179552,
               179747,
               179758,
               179838,
               179951,
               179991,
               180089,
               180191,
               180263,
               180443,
               180444,
               180445,
               180534,
               180584,
               180822
);
$two=0;
$one=0;
$counter=0;
foreach($number as $key => $row){
    $item=$row-$number[$counter+1];
    $counter++;
    if($item==-2) $two++;
    if($item==-1) $one++;
    $sum=$one+$two;
}
print_r("All: ".$sum."\n");
print_r("With -2: ".$two."\n");
print_r("With -1: ".$one."\n");
```

What can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: Check for the existence of the index before attempting to access it? e.g. like this: https://3v4l.org/usk7j

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regular `for` loop, and stop at the 2nd to last index.

```
for ($counter = 0; $counter < count($number)-1; $counter++) {
    $item = $number[$counter] - $number[$counter+1];
    if ($item == -2) {
        $two++;
    } elseif ($item == -1) {
        $one++;
    }
}
$sum = $one + $two;
```

There's no need to assign `$sum` each time through the loop, since you only use the final value.